# Java program throws exception if i add more participants in CC list

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

I have developed a below program to send the mail using java ail api , now it through error if i add more than one recipient in cc can you please advise how can i customise my below program so that i can add more people in cc , shall i go for an array for cc feild .

```
public class abctest{

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub


        String mailSmtpHost = "66.66.66.66;
        String mailSmtpPort = "1789" ;

        String mailTo = "ert@abc.com";
        String mailCc = "ewq@abc.com "; // ******throws exception if i add more than one email in cc list
        String mailFrom = "rrr@abc.com";
        String mailSubject = "Test Email from Java";
        String mailText = "This is an email for Brokerage  from Java";

        sendEmail(mailTo, mailCc, mailFrom, mailSubject, mailText, mailSmtpHost ,mailSmtpPort );
    }

    public static void sendEmail(String to, String cc, String from, String subject, String text, String smtpHost , String mailSmtpPort) {
        try {
            Properties properties = new Properties();
            properties.put("mail.smtp.host", smtpHost);
            properties.put("mailSmtpPort", mailSmtpPort);
            Session emailSession = Session.getDefaultInstance(properties);

            Message emailMessage = new MimeMessage(emailSession);
            emailMessage.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(to));
            emailMessage.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.CC, new InternetAddress(cc));
            emailMessage.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));
            emailMessage.setSubject(subject);

            emailMessage.setText(text);

            emailSession.setDebug(true);

            Transport.send(emailMessage);
        } catch (AddressException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (MessagingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
emailMessage.addRecipients(Message.RecipientType.CC, 
                    InternetAddress.parse("eranda@mahesh.com, mahesh@eranda.com"));
```

or

```
Address[] cc = new Address[] {new InternetAddress("eranda@mahesh.com"),
            new InternetAddress("mahesh@eranda.com")};
emailMessage.addRecipients(Message.RecipientType.CC, cc);
```

Comment: the second option is giving an error can you please advise how can i fix it as i want to embed in my above shown program